# Accessing synergy's options (windows 7/8)

Tags: synergy

This is probably a really stupid question, but...

I'm running synergy on a windows 8 server and on a windows 7 client. I was having trouble with full screen games losing focus, and I looked in the FAQ, which says:

> To prevent synergy from stealing the foreground just click
>   "Options..." and check "Don't take foreground window on Windows
>   servers.

I can't find "Options" anywhere. In fact, I can't find any sort of synergy screen. The only place I can even see it is in the task manager. When I first ran it, I got the configuration screen that was familiar from when I used it on Ubuntu. But when I run it now, it just starts up and, while it's configured properly (apart from games losing focus), I can't see any way to change anything if I need to. On ubuntu, I would be able to click the icon on the launch bar and select properties.

I was expecting an icon in the notification area, but even if I edit the notification are properties, there's no option to add synergy to the visible programs.

I also checked on the client machine, and there's no icon there either, so this is obviously normal, but I can't work out how I'm meant to access the options. Any solution for me is fine, but if I can add it to the notification are somehow, that would be great.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Synergy Server, do these steps:

1. Right click on the Synergy icon near the clock
2. Click **show** (the Synergy server window should appear)
3. Look for a button that says "Configure Server..." if it is not greyed out click it
4. On the window that appears look for "Advanced server settings"
5. On the right hand side you should see a section that says "Options"
   the option "Don't take foreground window on Windows servers" is there

I'm not sure how you would add to the notification area so good luck with that